# Iterate over HTMLElement attributes with colly?

Tags: go, go-colly

As seen in the HTML struct, the attributes is a private property:

```golang
// HTMLElement is the representation of a HTML tag.
type HTMLElement struct {
    // Name is the name of the tag
    Name       string
    Text       string
    attributes []html.Attribute
    // Request is the request object of the element's HTML document
    Request *Request
    // Response is the Response object of the element's HTML document
    Response *Response
    // DOM is the goquery parsed DOM object of the page. DOM is relative
    // to the current HTMLElement
    DOM *goquery.Selection
    // Index stores the position of the current element within all the elements matched by an OnHTML callback
    Index int
}
```

There are functions such a `.Attr()` for fetching a single attribute, but how would I iterate over all attributes? It seems that there is no obvious way to access `attributes` or functions from that struct.

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the raw `html.Node` underneath, we can iterate:

```golang
for _, node := range e.DOM.Nodes {
    fmt.Println(node.Attr)
}
```